# How to update table in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to update records in a table in MS Access 2007 from a temporary table. The temporary table gets new data from an external tool. The new data (2 columns) is supposed to go into the persistent table.

I tried the 2 following queries, but both show empty records when I look at the Datasheet view of the Query. (btw is there a better way to debug SQL in access?) The second Query also shows as many rows as there are in *table1* instead of only the amount of rows edited by the external tool. (in both cases, the results are empty for every row)

the version that has at least the right amount of records:

```
UPDATE (table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key)
SET table1.value1 = table2.value1, table1.datevalue = table2.datevalue
WHERE ((table1.value1) IS NULL);
```

the version with as many records as result as there are records in table1:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.value1 = (SELECT value1
FROM table2
WHERE ((table1.value1 IS NULL)
AND (table1.key = table2.key))),
table1.datevalue = (SELECT datevalue
FROM table2
WHERE ((table1.key = table2.key)
AND (table1.value1 IS NULL)))
```

In my test the tool manipulated 1 record so I expected to see one row as Output of the query with *value1* and *datevalue* from *table2*, yet the output shows *value1* and *datevalue* with empty entries (1 or (amount of records in *table1*)).

Comment: Please check the `SELECT` version of your update and subqueries: `SELECT table1.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.[key] = table2.[key] WHERE ((table1.value1) IS NULL)`. If zero rows result then there are simply no records that match to `JOIN` and `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: @Parfait I tried the select version (in the form you suggested). The result was 1 row (which is correct as i changed 1 row in the test) with the values matching as expected

Comment: Then just run the update inside Access GUI's query window (see run icon) and check message prompt to see how many records will update. You can always rollback by canceling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
show empty records when I look at the Datasheet view of the Query
```

If you openn Update query in table mode, you will see only current values of the cells. You should run (execute) your query in order to get values updated. Update query cannot be checked for preview (as you want, as I understood).

Comment: I see. You understood that correctly, that's exactly what I wanted to do. I need to ask, however, how do I run the query? A right click does not seem to show any option of running the query.

Comment: I found it. Damn, I'm a f*** ..not smart. It worked and the update worked as expected after actually running the query. I'm gonna go hit my head into a wall. Thanks for your help.

Comment: From GUI: press `!` button; from VBA code: use DAO.QueryDef Execute method, or DoCmd.RunSQL workaround. Everything comes up with expirience, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To fully answer your questions, action queries including `UPDATE` and `INSERT` in the MS Access .exe program will raise a message prompt by default to inform the user how many rows will be updated or inserted and if user wants to continue with the action. Other views of action queries may not inform affected records.

[image: Access GUI Message]

This message will pop up if action query is called from:

- Query Design window using the run action `!` icon
- Macro using [OpenQuery](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/openquery-macro-action-d3f1eed8-9cc4-4962-9039-f4ae5966ccf5) action
- Module using [DoCmd.OpenQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openquery) command

If not using MS Access .exe (since Access is both an application program and a database), you can still see how many records are affecting via code using DAO's [Database.RecordsAffected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-recordsaffected-property-dao) property which is part of the MS Access object library. Any COM-interfaced language can run the same process including VBA, Python, PHP, Java, etc.

**VBA Example** *(note: VBA is a separate component to MS Access and other Office apps)*

```vb
Sub RunUpdate()    
   Dim db as DAO.Database

   Set db = CurrentDb()
   db.Execute "mySavedUpdateQuery"

   MsgBox CStr(db.RecordsAffected) & " records were affected."    

   Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Python Example**

```py
import os
import win32com.client

access_file = r'C:\Path\To\MyDatabase.accdb'

try:
    oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
    oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(access_file)

    db = oApp.Currentdb()
    db.Execute("EmployeesUpdateQ")
    print("{} records were affected.".format(db.RecordsAffected))

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    oApp.Quit()
    db = None; oApp = None
    del db; del oApp
```

---

### Number of Rows Question

Both your queries will update different number of records. First version maintains a `JOIN` and `WHERE` condition on outer level so will affect a filtered number of records in *table1*.

```sql
UPDATE (table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.[key] = t2.[key])
SET t1.value1 = t2.value1, 
    t1.datevalue = t2.datevalue
WHERE ((t1.value1) IS NULL);
```

Second version uses subqueries with `JOIN` and `WHERE` conditions but nothing on outer level and so all records of *table1* will be affected but specific values may update to `NULL`. In fact, you may receive an exception error if subqueries return more than one value:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET table1.value1 = (SELECT value1
                     FROM table2
                     WHERE ((table1.value1 IS NULL)
                       AND  (table1.[key] = table2.[key]))),

    table1.datevalue = (SELECT datevalue
                        FROM table2
                        WHERE ((table1.[key] = table2.[key])
                          AND  (table1.value1 IS NULL)))
```